# react widget multiselect - customize closing x

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to replace the 'x' character that removes a selected tag in the Multiselect widget. If possible, I would like to replace it with an icon I will provide, and that would be the best solution. I could also settle for manipulating it with css, but for some reason the 'x' appears broken in my Chrome:

[image]

Edit: I'm using the npm module `react-widgets`

Thanks.

Comment: which npm mpdule are you using?

Comment: @Krina I have installed it with `npm install react-widgets --save`

Comment: Seems like library is not providing you any props to handle it.